# Python inheritance issues

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, attributes

I have a class Person which contains a number of attributes, one of which is an inventory attribute:

```
class Person:
        def __init__(self):
            #Private Attributes
            self._inventory = []
```

I have a child class Male, which inherits from the Person class:

```
class Male(Person):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Person, self).__init__()
```

Inside of the Person class is a method HasItem:

```
def HasItem(self, key):
            item = next(filter(lambda x: key in x.Key, self._inventory), None)

            if (not item == None):
                if (item.Quantity == 0):
                    self._inventory.remove(next(filter(lambda x: item.Key in x.Key, self._inventory)))
                    return False
                else:
                    return True
            else:
                return False
```

I also have a class called NPC which takes a Person object as an argument:

```
class NPC():
        def __init__(self, person, *args, **kwargs):
            self._person = person

        @property
        def Person(self):
            return self._person
```

So I instantiate an instance of NPC:

```
npc = NPC(Male(Person()))
```

and then call npc.Person.HasItem("Key"), at which point I get an error saying that "'Male' object has no attribute '_inventory'"

As Male is inheriting from Person, and the HasItem method is in Person, I would expect it to use the self._inventory from Person. Yet it appears it wants Male to also have an attribute self._inventory which would make the whole point of inheritance useless. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `super` takes the *current* class, not the parent class (or in Python 3 you can just leave out the arguments).

Comment: Oh for the love of.... [insert Aladdin I feel sheepish meme here]... thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the `Male` class `__init__` method. The super takes in subclass name instead of parent class name and object.
Possible fixes:

```
class Male(Person):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Male, self).__init__()
```

or

```
class Male(Person):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
```